# How to retrieve command-line args which was passed during building [custom build system] in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I know how to retrieve command-line args in JS by using following manner,

```
`Config.getTestArgs = () => {
    try {
        return global.commandLineArgs.args["test-args"];
    }
    catch (e) {
        logger.error(`Error reading test - args from command line: ${ e } `);
        return null;
    }
};`
```

When i use the same way in Typescript, i get an error `Cannot find module- global`

If i pass my input like

```
`--build --test-args TestArument1`
```

`getTestArgs` should return TestArgument1 as output.

Consider we have our own build system which uses nodeJs and Typescript. Which nodeJS dependencies should i need to consider?

Comment: Is your JS example using a third-party package to extract the command line arguments (perhaps [command-line-args](https://www.npmjs.com/package/command-line-args))? `global.commandLineArgs.args` is not a standard way to retrieve command line arguments as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Yes it does uses 3rd party packages,. Can you please standard way to retrieve command line arguments in TS?

Comment: Using a third party package is not bad in and of itself, but if you do you probably don't need to use the `global` object. The 'standard' way is to use `process.argv.slice(2)`, which returns an array of all the arguments passed into the process. A more robust way would be to use something like [minimist](https://github.com/substack/minimist) to do the parsing for you. What library are you currently using to parse the command line arguments?

Comment: @Fdebijl your suggestion works perfectly. Thank you so much !! :)

Comment: No problem! I'll port my comment to an answer so you can mark this question as closed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Typescript and Node.js in general, there's a few ways to retrieve command line arguments. You can either use the built-in [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) property, which returns an array containing the command line arguments passed when the Node.js process was launched. Since the first two arguments will almost always be `node` and `path/to/script.js`, it is generally used as `process.argv.slice(2)`.

**Example:**

```bash
node script.js --build --test-args TestArgument1
```

*script.js*

```js
console.log(process.argv.slice(2)) // [ '--build', '--test-args', 'TestArgument1' ]
```

---

The other, arguably better, way is to use a tried and tested library to parse your command line arguments. Popular options include:

**[Minimist](https://github.com/minimistjs/minimist)**: For minimal argument parsing.

**[Commander.js](https://github.com/tj/commander.js)**: Most adopted module for argument parsing.

**[Meow](https://github.com/sindresorhus/meow)**: Lighter alternative to Commander.js

**[Yargs](https://github.com/bcoe/yargs)**: More sophisticated argument parsing (heavy).

**[Vorpal.js](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal)**: Mature / interactive command-line applications with argument parsing.

For your case Minimist would probably the best solution.
`node script.js --build --test-args TestArgument1` would look like this:

```js
const argv: minimist.ParsedArgs = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
console.dir(argv); 
/*
 { 
   _: [ 'build' ],
   test-args: 'TestArgument1'
 }
*/
```

Comment: Minimist URL: https://github.com/minimistjs/minimist